# How get position of a child with respect to it's parent in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

```dart
Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: [
                        GestureDetector(
                          onPanDown: (d) {
                            RenderBox box = _key.currentContext!
                                .findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                            Offset position = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
                            print(position);
                            setState(() {
                              value.offset = Offset(position.dx / screen.width,
                                  position.dy / screen.height);
                            });
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            key: _key,
                            height: value.height,
                            width: value.width,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
```

When I tap on the container, I want to get the position of the container with respect to parent which is the stack widget.

Comment: *"I want to get the position of the container with respect to parent"* - if i get you correctly, check all the params you can pass to `RenderBox.localToGlobal` method

Comment: @pskink can you please share code snippet, it would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderBox/localToGlobal.html - they say: *"If ancestor is non-null, this function converts the given point to the coordinate system of ancestor (which must be an ancestor of this render object) instead of to the global coordinate system."*